# i try to send notification to specific device using firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am building chat app with flutter and I try to send notification to specific device using the cloud function so when a user send message to his friend then his friend get notification with the message but I get that error

note : I don not have any knowledge with javascript or node js

> Unhandled error Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
> at Object.validateResourcePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:446:15)
> at CollectionReference.doc (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2061:20)
> at /workspace/index.js:14:12
> at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:72:41)
> at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:407:32
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

first I try to get the device token and save it to firebase

```
 void getToken() async {
await fcm.getToken().then((value) {
  tokens = value;

  print('my token22 is $tokens');
  saveToken(tokens: tokens);
});
 }

 void saveToken({String? tokens}) async {
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userToken').doc(userphone).set({
    'token': tokens,
    });
  }
```

then I try to call this token at index.js file at function function

```
   const functions = require("firebase-functions");

   const admin = require("firebase-admin");

   admin.initializeApp();

  exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall(
  (data, context) => {
   const friendPhone = data.text;
   const userDoc = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("userToken")
      .doc(friendPhone)
      .get();
  const deviceTokens = userDoc.data();
  console.log(deviceTokens);
  const title = data.title;
  const body = data.body;

  try {
    if (deviceTokens) {
      exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
          .document("chats/{chatId}/messegeId/{messageId}")
          .onWrite((snap, context) => {
            console.log(snap.data());

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens,
                {
                  notification: {title: title,
                    body: body,
                    clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                  },
                });
          });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new functions.https.
        HttpsError("invalid-argument", "some message");
  }
}
);
```

after that I call the function at sendMessege button so that when the user send messgege it work

```
  Future<void> writeMessage({
  String? message,
  String? title,
  String? friendPhone,
 }) async {
  HttpsCallable callable =
    FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("addMessage");
  final resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
  "text": friendPhone,
  "title": title,
  "body": message,
  });
  print("result: ${resp.data}");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

oare you sure that the path for the friendPhone is a valid path in firebase?

Is there maybe a spelling mistake in messageId?

```
document("chats/{chatId}/messegeId/{messageId}")
```

You wrote messegeId instead of messageId

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i sure it is the right path i take it copy and past from database